# Invalid escape sequence lua regex

Tags: regex, nginx, lua, pcre

I've written a regex to match the below string type which is working as expected when I check it online in regex matcher-

```
"['432', '212']"

regex - "(\[)('([^']|'')*'), ('([^']|'')*')(])"

ngx.re.find(string, "\"(\[)('([^']|'')*'), ('([^']|'')*')(])\"", "jo")
```

When I'm using this inside lua block to match the string it's giving me invalid escape sequence error.
i escaped the double quotes and tried to escape the special the character in regex as well with the \ but still, the issue persists. any pointer will help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `local regex = [["(\[)('([^']|'')*'), ('([^']|'')*')(])"]]`?

Comment: I don't know lua, but in many languages, `\ ` is special in string literals, so you actually have to use `\\[` to pass `\[` to the regex engine to match a literal `[`.

Comment: @ikegami - yeah u right it's PCRE. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll restate what people said in the comments. You've used `\[` in your regex, which is a quoted string. In a quoted string, a backslash begins an escape sequence, but `\[` is an invalid escape sequence (see [the Lua 5.1 manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.1) for valid escape sequences), so the Lua parser is complaining about it. Vanilla Lua 5.1 just removes the backslash (which would be bad in this regex), while Lua 5.3 and LuaJIT complain about it.

You can remove the parse error and make sure that the backslash is actually inserted into the string by escaping it with another backslash – `"\\["` – as you would have to do in JavaScript when using the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), or by using a long string, which doesn't interpret escape sequences – `[[\[]]`. If you use a long string, you also have to replace escaped double quotes `\"` in your regular expression with just plain `"`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer to write a parser even for the most simple patterns.  It is much more flexible than a Regex and remains readable even when it grows larger.  Below I show a parser for the expression you want to match using [LPEG](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html).

You can find a good LPEG tutorial here: http://leafo.net/guides/parsing-expression-grammars.html

```
local lpeg = assert(require("lpeg"))
local C, Ct, P, R, S = lpeg.C, lpeg.Ct, lpeg.P, lpeg.R, lpeg.S

-- optional whitespace (zero or more)
local ws = S" \n\r\t"^0

-- quoted integer, converted to number
local quot = P"'" * C(R"09"^1) / tonumber * P"'"

-- integer followed by zero or more commas followed by integer
local list = quot * ws * (P"," * ws * quot)^0

-- [ followed by list of integers captured in a table followed by ]
local rule = P"[" * ws * Ct(list) * ws * P"]"

-- match the string and collect results
local nums = rule:match("['432', '212']")

-- print result table
print(table.concat(nums,","))
```

```
$ lua test.lua 
432,212
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you wrap require in assert?

Comment: @dualed I know that `lpeg` is supposed to return a table.  If it returns `nil` then I know that the wrong module was loaded.  This is not too uncommon if you have a project with many files and one of the files has accidentally the same name as a module.  Or if you are in an embedding scenario, the application might disable certain libraries by setting them to `nil` (applications embedding LuaJIT sometimes disable `ffi` for security reasons).